# What do I need to play HDMI/DVI/1080i through my PC?

Tags: hdmi

This seems silly... I am just looking for a way to use HDMI, DVI, or another 1080p compatible source to play on my desktop (Either in a window or fullscreen). Not the other way around - I want to plug a device (Console, Bluray player, whatever) into my computer and watch the video on my desktop.

**I already use the device plugged into my monitor.** But I want it to go through my PC.

My graphics card (EVGA 550ti) has an HDMI slot, but apparently that is only for video output - not input.

The only device I could find that seemed to offer what I am looking for costs a small fortune ($170): [AVerMedia Live Gamer HD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815100100). There is an older model, but it only supports 720p.

Is there really no other way to use my computer for video input? Is there any sort of driver configuration to use that HDMI port as an input? Do I really have to spend over $150 to do this?

I can't really believe that it's going to cost more for this device than it did for my graphics card. You would think the graphics card would be much more expensive than the input device...

Comment: $150 is a decent price, usually only professional grade gfx cards will support full hdmi input/capture > http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/

Comment: Avermedia makes some cheap: http://www.avermedia-usa.com/avertv/estore/estore.html

Comment: After doing a bit more research, I guess @logman is right. The cheaper options are USB or standalone recorders. I guess getting it to display on your PC at full 1080p resolution isn't going to be cheap. A lot of lower end cards are limited quality/resolution or otherwise have really *really* bad reviews.